# Text not aligning in CSS animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am currently working on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/4p6Lk/9/) but I am not sure how I can arrange the text on several lines as a paragraph instead of on Just one line, I find that when I insert more text, as I have overflow hidden, it seems to just carry on in one line out of the div. I would like to be able to have a paragraph in my spinning div.

I have tried < p > tags and < br > tags but neither of these work.

HTML

```
<div class="hover-img">
Text Goes Here
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hover-img {
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
background:url(http://www.wholesaleforeveryone.com/content/images/blank/600/solid_color.gif);
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    line-height:200px;
text-align:center;
font-size:0;

}
.hover-img:hover{
-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);
font-size:14px;
color:white;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css property `word-wrap: break-word;` and reduce the `line-height:200px;` to value like `15px;`

```
.hover-img {
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
background:url(http://www.wholesaleforeveryone.com/content/images/blank/600/solid_color.gif);
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
line-height:15px;
text-align:center;
font-size:0;
word-wrap:break-word;

}
```

demo http://codepen.io/krish4u/pen/sijrC

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `line-height` on `.hover-img`
2. Add `display: table` to `.hover-img`
3. Wrap the text in another div (`.text`) and use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` on that div to align the text vertically in the centre.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/4p6Lk/14/)

HTML

```
<div class="hover-img">
    <div class="text">
        Text Goes Here
        <br />And Here
        <br />And Here
        <br />And Here
        <br />And Here
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hover-img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align:center;
    display: table;
    background: /* whatever value */
}
.hover-img:hover {
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
}
.text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```